# How to finish my Python egg-tossing game?

Tags: python-3.x

When I started I thought I had a firm grasp on how I was going to do it, but as I kept typing I started to get lost. I began building it because I just learned about booleans and conditionals so I wanted to try them out.

The purpose of the game was to first guess the correct number then be able to throw a specific egg so the coinciding cleaning supplies would run out in order to get a car out of the 'dirty' state. Not much of a fun game but I want to see how it would turn out.

```
import random
name = input("hey, tell me your name!:")
print("well " + name + " if you can guess the number I'm thinking of, I'll let you throw an egg at my car")
number = random.randint (1, 100)
GuessesTaken = 0
Ammo = input('which egg will you use?')
How_hard = int(input('how hard do you throw?:\n\t'))
cleaning_supplies = ['windex', 'wipers', 'shamwow', 'sponge']
eggs = ['robin', 'ostrich', 'hen', 'Pterodactyls']
Velocity = {'robin' : 4, 'ostrich' : 10, 'hen' : 6, 'pterodactyls' : 15,}
pairings = {'windex' : 'robin', 'wipers' : 'ostrich', 'shamwow' : 'hen', 'sponge' : 'pterodactyles'}
# the eggs are hitting a car which then turns clean (false)
dirty = True
hit = cleaning_supplies.pop()
egg = (input(' :\n\t'))
while GuessesTaken < 5:
    guess = input("enter a num: ")
    GuessesTaken = GuessesTaken + 1
    guess = int(guess)
    if guess < number:
        print("Not High Enough!")
    elif guess > number:
     else:
     break
```

Please don't fully type out the proper code and submit it, I'm just looking for some clues.

Why is the else statement underlined as wrong?

Comment: It looks like your indentation is not even. The `if` statement is indented four spaces, and the `print` is indented eight. The `elif` is indented four, all of which looks right. But then the `else` is indented five. You also don't have any code in your `elif`, perhaps you only need an `else`?

Answer (score 0):

The gist:

```
def consider_guess(guess, target):
    if guess < target:
        return (False, "Too small")  # Read about tuples. Tuples are your friend.
    if guess > target:
        return (False, "Too big")
    # The only remaining possibility is equality.
    return (True, "Yes, you guessed it!")

while ...:
    guess = int(input_raw("Your guess? "))
    (is_correct, message) = consider_guess(guess, ...)
    print(message)
    if is_correct:
        break
```